# implement Single page architecture using javascript for my website where i need to start?

Tags: single-page-application

I want to implement Single page architecture using javascript for my website where i need to start?

```
window.onload= function ()
{

    var x=  hometemplate.home.statictemplateHome();
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = x;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is a popular web framework supporting SPA and
it has a **simple tutorial** you can follow by yourself

## https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00

---

BTW welcome to Stack Overflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask